# Weird result when calculating the deviation of 2 functions (2 examples)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In the final step of this program it takes a huge amount of time to complete
and the result I get is a bit weird. I was waiting for some number in scientific notation format.

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + x^2) + Log[x + 1];
xM = 10;
xm = 0; (* Domeniul de definitie, extins in afara lui [-1,1]*)

g1 = Print[Plot[f[x], {x, xm, xM}, PlotStyle -> Blue]];
Na = 40;
For[
  k = 0, k <= Na, k++,
  c[k] = 2/Na \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(Na\)]\(f[\((Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(\((2  j - 1)\) 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\), \(Na\)]])\)\ 
\*FractionBox[\(xM - xm\), \(2\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(xM + xm\), \(2\)]] \((Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(k \((2  j - 1)\) 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\), \(Na\)]])\)\)\)
  ];
(*Se calculeaza coeficienti de interpolare Chebyshev pentru f(x) - \
CDT *)
p[x_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(Na\)]\(c[n] Cos[
      n\ ArcCos[2\ 
\*FractionBox[\(x - xm\), \(xM - xm\)] - 1]]\)\) + 1/2 c[0];
(*Aici incepe derivarea numerica*)
b[Na + 1] = 0;
b[Na] = 0;
For[k = Na, k > 0, k--,
  b[k - 1] = b[k + 1] + 2 k c[k];
  ];
dp[x_] := 2/(xM - xm)*(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(Na\)]\(b[n] Cos[
        n\ *ArcCos[2\ 
\*FractionBox[\(x - xm\), \(xM - xm\)] - 1]]\)\) + 1/2 b[0]);
df[x_] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[
   x]\)\); (*Derivata analitica pentru comparatie *)
g3 = 
 Plot[df[x], {x, xm, xM}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All];
g4 = Plot[dp[x], {x, xm, xM}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All];
Print[Show[g3, g4]];

Nm = 500; (*Nr de puncte in care se calculeaza abaterea*)
lst = {};
For[i = 1, i < Nm, i++, 
  r[i] = xm + i (xM - xm)/Nm; 
  
  AppendTo[lst, Abs[df[r[i]] - dp[r[i]]]];
  ];
Print[Max[Sort[lst]]];
```

The block that is giving me issues is:

```
Nm=500; (*Nr de puncte in care se calculeaza abaterea*)
lst={};
For[i=1, i<Nm, i++, 
r[i]=xm+i (xM-xm)/Nm; 

AppendTo[lst, Abs[df[r[i]]-dp[r[i]]]];
];
Print[Max[Sort[lst]]]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

I found the same issue in another exercise where we want to establish the error between two ways to calculate the integral of a function.
[image: Integral with simpson part 1]
[image: Integral with simpson part2]

Instead I get:

[image: What I get instead]

Comment: Davide, you must put a space between k and h. This space is equivalent to a multiplication symbol. Look at the difference between your last two images. Notice how the k and h have spacing in the 2nd to last image, but in the last one there is none. This can further be confirmed by observing that the k is blue (undefined) and h is black (defined) whereas in the last image kh is blue (undefined) because kh, a new symbol, is not yet defined. Tl;dr `k h == k*h =/= kh`.

Answer (score 1):

First, this will not work with a numerical argument

```
df[x_] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[x]\)\);
```

You may use the following, but you must take care that x has no value, e.g.:

```
x=.; df[x_] = D[df[x],x]
```

Further, you should not use AppendTo inside a loop, because this allocates each time new memory. Instead write something like:

```
lst=Reap[
   For[i=1,i<10,i++, Sow[i]]
]
```

Third, if possible do not calculate with rational numbers but use real numbers. E.g.

```
 r[i] = xm + k (xM - xm)/Nm   // N;
```

Forth, if you do not need r[i] later do not store it, use r instead:

```
 r = xm + k (xM - xm)/Nm   // N;
```